# html5 error using IE8

Tags: javascript, css, html, internet-explorer-8

I'm having trouble with ie8 using html5 and Css3 (I think).

With Firefox and Chrome it works perfectly.

When I try to open the website using ie8 all my header put into my body....

css

```
 .main-header {
     font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
     font-size: 14px;
     font-weight: bold;
     letter-spacing: 2px;
     color: #000;
     white-space: nowrap;
     padding: 10px;
     background-color: #FFF;
     background-position: right top;
     border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
     background: url(/images/header_bg.png);
 }

 .main-header2{
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    color: #000;
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    background-position: right top;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
    background: url(/images/header_bg.png);
 }


 .main-headertmp {
   font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
   font-size: 16px;
   font-weight: bold;
   color: #000000;
   letter-spacing: 4px;
   white-space: nowrap;
   margin-bottom: 1px;
   border-bottom: 4px solid #4571d4;
   background-color: #FFFFFF;
   background: url(/images/header_bg.jpg);
  }

 html,
 body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
 }

 #content {
  padding:10px;
  padding-bottom:80px; /* Height of the footer element */
 }

  #container {
    min-height:100%;
    position:relative;
    height:100%;
  }

 #header {
         background-color: #FFF;
         background-position: right top;
         border-bottom: 1px solid #C64934;
         background: url(../images/header_bg.png);
  }

  #body {
    padding:10px;
    padding-bottom: 60px;   /* Height of the footer */
    color : #333;
    background-color: #FFF;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
 }

 #footer {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
    height:60px;   /* Height of the footer */
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    background: #F1F3F5;
    border-top: 1px solid #cccccc;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc;
 }
```

index header ->script

```
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="/javascript/modernzr.js">
        document.createElement(\'container\');
        document.createElement(\'header\');
        document.createElement(\'body\');
        document.createElement(\'footer\');
      </script>
    <![endif]-->
```

those element are using on divs.

```
 <div id="container">
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="body"></div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
 </div>
```

someone could help me ?

thank you.

Comment: IE8 does not support css3...

Comment: On a sidenote - You create a `container` element. There is no such element in HTML5.

Comment: you are missing the display:block rule for these and body is not to be created again :)

Comment: Having a script with both `src` and a body won't work.

Comment: Why are there backslashes before all quotes?

Comment: echo ' <script> document-createelement(\'id\');

Comment: Even if the script did run, you are not appending those elements anywhere. Even if you did append them, what for?

Comment: @JanDvorak these statement are needed for IE<9 to correctly handle those html5 elements. they are the main statements of html5 shim/v. it doesn't matter if they are not appended anywhere

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you cannot include a `script` with both a `src` and a text inside the block, so you need to include two different `script` blocks. Also backslashes are not needed, so use this code instead

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script>
    document.createElement('container'); 
    document.createElement('header');
    document.createElement('footer');
  </script>
  <script src="/javascript/modernzr.js"> </script>
<![endif]-->
```

Note: in HTML5 there's no a `container` element (yet?) defined on the language specs: maybe you wanted to create a `main` element instead.

Comment: Sry I forgot to write those lines.....i edited my script... using both <script>, u said something about container element, how can I define it. or just i won't be able to run it using ie8 ?

Comment: @StriderWaR technically you can use any element on modern browser: e.g. `<whatever>You can style me</whatever>` and on older IE you can equally use `document.createElement('whatever')`, but I would not recommend to use tags not defined on specs